# How to determine the foliation which integrates a 1-dimensional distribution?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, foliations

The question is as follows:

In the 3-sphere $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4 $ consider the 1-dimensional distribution defined by
$$X = -y \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y } - \omega \frac{\partial}{\partial z } + z \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega }$$
Determine the foliation $F$ integrating this distribution.

$\textbf{Some attempt:}$

Let $\gamma (t) = (x(t ), y(t), z(t), \omega (t))$, with initial point $\gamma (0) = (x_0, y_0, z_0 , \omega_0)$. Hence, $\gamma'(t)=(x'(t ), y'(t), z'(t), \omega' (t))$, where 
$$ \begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt} = -y \\ \frac{dy}{dt} = x \end{cases} ~~~~ \text{and}~~~~ \begin{cases} \frac{dz}{dt} = -\omega \\ \frac{d\omega}{dt} = z \end{cases}$$
From where this suggests we try $x(t) = A \cos t$ and plugging this into the second equation gives $y(t) = A \sin t$, and it's easy to check that this choice of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ solves the second equation in the first system. And the same for second system, we have $z(t) = B \cos t$ and $\omega (t) = B \sin t$.

So we have $\gamma (t) = (A \cos t , A \sin t , B \cos t, B \sin t)$ with $\gamma (0) = (A, 0 , B, 0)$. So we get $A = x_0$ and $B=z_0$.

Can some one please let me know if I am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is fine. By the way, a 1 -dimensional distribution is usually called a vector field. Now all you need to do is understand what the resulting foliation looks like.

Comment: @Danu: Not quite — a $1$-dimensional distribution is a *line* field, not a vector field.

Comment: @Danu Many thanks! Can you please let me know how to know the resulting foliation looks like what?

Comment: @Danu Many thanks! Can you please let me know what can be the resulting foliation?

Answer (score 3):

So the question seems rather to be: how do I understand the shape of the curve $\gamma(t)$ inside $\mathbb S^3$?
There are a number of ways.

The easiest may be the following: choose a point $N$ such that: $\gamma(t)\ne N$ for any $t$. Now you can use the fact that $\mathbb S^3\setminus N$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$ (via stereographic projection from $N$). Composing $\gamma$ with the stereographic projection gives you a (closed) curve in $\mathbb R^3$ that you can visualize easily.

The previous one was not much specific of your curve and can be done for every curve in $\mathbb S^3$. For something more tailored on this $\gamma$ you should consider that your curve lies on the two hyperplanes $x_1/A-x_3/B=0$ and $x_2/A-x_4/B=0$ (here I'm assuming $A\ne0\ne B$), and both hyperplanes are through the origin. Therefore your curve sits inside a $2$-plane through the center intersecting the $3$-sphere and it should be then easy to convince you that this is nothing but a great circle on $\mathbb S^3$.

Then try and understand what happens when changing to various choices of $A$ and $B$...

Comment: Many thanks for your knowledgeable answer! But can you please let me know why our curve lies on the two hyperplanes $x_1/A-x_3/B=0$ and $x_2/A-x_4/B=0$? Is there any observation to see that?

Comment: It was just easy to see that such equations are satisfied by looking at the explicit form of $\gamma$. Of course it also does belong to generalized cylinders like $(x_1/A)^2+(x_2/A)^2=1$ and the like for $x_3,x_4$...

Comment: Many thanks! I understood that. You talked about cylinders, can you also please let me know why there is no integral manifolds in the example attached to this comment [linked to the result][1]                                      [1]:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571733/show-that-the-2-dimensional-distribution-in-mathbbr3-has-no-integral-manif?noredirect=1#comment5332986_2571733